# Hide on not hover - BOOTSTRAP TOGGABLE PILLS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap toggable pills with some modifications to work vertical.

I want the contant-tab to disappear when I live the pill.

I tried but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container" style="width:80%; height:720px; padding:0; margin:0;">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-2"  id="pills-first" style="padding:120px 0px 120px 0px;">
        <li><a href="#tab_a" style="padding:20px 0px 20px 0px; text-align:center;"><img src="images/gallery-learn.png" style="width:80px; height:80px; margin:0; padding:0;"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_b" style="padding:20px 0px 20px 0px; text-align:center;"><img src="images/gallery-speak.png" style="width:80px; height:80px; margin:0; padding:0;"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_c" style="padding:20px 0px 20px 0px; text-align:center;"><img src="images/gallery-read.png" style="width:80px; height:80px; margin:0; padding:0;"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_d" style="padding:20px 0px 20px 0px; text-align:center;"><img src="images/gallery-write.png" style="width:80px; height:80px; margin:0; padding:0;"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content col-sm-6" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="tab_a" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); height:600px; margin:60px 0px 60px 0px; padding:10px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <h4>Pane A</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_b" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); height:600px; margin:60px 0px 60px 0px; padding:10px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <h4>Pane B</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_c" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); height:600px; margin:60px 0px 60px 0px; padding:10px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <h4>Pane C</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_d" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); height:600px; margin:60px 0px 60px 0px; padding:10px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <h4>Pane D</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- tab content -->
</div><!-- end of container -->
```

and this the JS

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js</script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#pills-first a').hover(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show')
   });
</script>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What's the reason of preventDefault on hover?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a style of display : none; then change the css "none" to "block" when you want it to show.

Use

```
$("#pill-first a").css("display" : "block")
```

Comment: Oh you also didn't end your jquery statements in the code above.

Comment: Use $("#pills-first a").css({"display" : "block"});

Comment: You also need to do two functions for your hover function a handler in and a handler out or else the css will stay the same after you hover on then off look at https://api.jquery.com/hover/